# How to disable password needed for hibernation after inactivity on kali linux

Tags: gnome, power-management, password, hibernate, kali-linux-tools

I have my kali linux configured to automatically hibernate after 40minutes of inactivity but it always asks for a password. How do i disable the password so it hibernates automatically

Comment: Kali is off-topic on AskUbuntu, and is intended for use by experts.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We are sorry, Kali Linux is off-topic. You can use https://forums.kali.org/ but expect them to be very harsh: Kali is intended for experienced GNU/Linux users and users are expected to fix their own problems and only when that fails to have them ask a question with a well-documented problem.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site.  https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/